# Maven EAR Plugin Modules

Tags: java, maven, ejb, java-ee-7

To build a Java EE application with Maven, one can use the following configuration:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                           [..]
                        </webModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            [..]
                        </ejbModule>
                        <jarModule>
                            [..]
                        </jarModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I understand that the web module is packaged differently from other modules, that is, for example, being located at the root of the ear and having packed it's own dependencies to `WEB-INF/lib`.

But what about jar and ejb modules? How are they different from each other?
And what is the difference of defining a jar as a normal dependency and/or defining it as a `jarModule` or `ejbModule`?

Beeing more precise, what is the difference between the following setups:

**1. ejb module defined as ejbModule**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            [..]
                        </webModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                             <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                             <artifactId>helloworld-model</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<dependencies>
    
</dependencies>
```

**2. ejb module defined as dependency**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            [..]
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <depdendency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>helloworld-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**3. ejb/jar defined as jarModule**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            [..]
                        </webModule>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                             <artifactId>helloworld-model</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </jarModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**4. ejb/jar defined as dependency**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            [..]
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <depdendency>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>helloworld-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer a part of your question:

EJB artifacts go to the main directory of the EAR, while JAR artifacts go to the `lib` dir.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the difference is if the jar lies on the root or in the lib folder?